# change part of a php file using php

Tags: php

how can I change only a part of php file. Actually add a variable or change a single variable in already existing php file. I have tried as follows but this erases everything and echoes only the text "I love PHP".

```
$myFile = '../new_folder_name/index.php'; 
$myContent = 'I love PHP'; 

file_put_contents($myFile, utf8_encode($myContent));
```

I want to add for example a variable named $test that equals 10. `$test="10";` or change already existing variable `$test` to 10.

Comment: Why do you need to call `file_put_contents()`?

Comment: You read in the file, manipulate its contents in memory, then spit it out again. or read the file line-by-line, find the one line you do want to change, change it, then write out the lines (modified or not) to another file until you're done. then delete the original file, rename the new file, and boom... contents changed.

Comment: An editor seems a good idea...

Comment: you don't want that. dynamic code modification is a hell for debugging and an open door for vulnerabilities

Comment: @Dieter: What does AJAX have to do with this question?  Did you even read the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this for adding new content**

```
$myFile = '../new_folder_name/index.php'; 
$myContent = 'I love PHP';
$file=fopen($myFile,"a");
fputs($file,$myContent);
fclose($file);
```

For playing with variables we need to handle an php file as an normal text file here you go

```
function get_str_btwn($string, $start, $end)//an function to get string between two string in an string
{
    $string = " " . $string;
    $ini    = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0)
        return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
$file=file_get_contents($myFile);
if(substr_count($file,"$myContent"))
$file=str_ireplace(get_str_btwn($file,"$myContent =",";"),"I love PHP",$file);//Assuming format of php file is $myContent is initialized like $myContent="something"; 
else
$file=str_ireplace("<?php","<?php $myContent = 'I love PHP';",$file);
```

Please note this code is very sensitive and may result in errors in php file generated and is not recommended for regular use unless you are sure format of php file.

Comment: that is the one, how can I now play with the variables. How could I in $mycontent add a $test variable or a new value for a test variable

Comment: the only thing is that the code appears at the bottom of the changing code.

Answer (score 1):

I am creating php file with php file

```
<?php
$dir = "../new_folder_name";

$file_to_write = "index.php";

$content_to_write = '


PHP CODE COMES HERE
$test= GET ('SOMETHING')


';

if( is_dir($dir) === false )
{
mkdir($dir);
}

$file = fopen($dir . '/' . $file_to_write,"w");

fwrite($file, $content_to_write);

fclose($file);

include $dir . '/' . $file_to_write;
?>
```

I want everyfile to have a different value of a $test variable. I wanted after a file creation to be able to change the value of the variable in the created file